# Nested for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

There's one thing bugging me about this code

```
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
          for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)                  
              if(i == c)
                  System.out.print("*");
              else
                  System.out.print("-");

        System.out.println(".");
    }
```

I know the inner for-loop has to complete before the outer-loop can loop again. Why is it that the System.out.println(".") only occurs once in the inner loop even though it should loop multiple times?

Comment: You should use else{ ----code----} for printing multiple line, otherwise it will take only single line.

Comment: Protip: *always* use braces with flow-control constructs. (Until you're a pro, then still heed the previous statement.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
System.out.println(".");
```

is outside the nested `for`. If you want it inside, you should use brackets `{}`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
        if (i == c) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println(".");
    }
}
```

Remember that if you don't put brackets `{}`, the body of the `for` loop will only be one statement (the one which is next to the `for` declaration).

Answer (score 2):

because it is out side of inner for loop, use parentheses around for loop body for better readability and to avoid such confusion

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you were expecting, but your code is equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
      for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
          if(i == c) {
              System.out.print("*");
          } else {
              System.out.print("-");
          }
      }

      System.out.println("."); // This is OUTSIDE the inner loop.
}
```

Moral of the story: When in doubt, use parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Your final statement is part of the outer loop.

> System.out.println(".");

Since you have  a single if-else statement in the inner loop, braces were not needed.
Always use braces to define the scope of the loop and for the sake of readability.

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
      for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {                 
          if(i == c) {
              System.out.print("*");
          } 
          else {
              System.out.print("-");
          } 
      }

    System.out.println(".");
}
```

Comment: You've said "always use braces", then left them out of the `if/else`.  This answer would be better if the code snippet matched the advice.

Comment: My purpose what to show what code given in the question will looks like if braces were provided.

Answer (score 1):

Inner loop must complete all of it's passes/times and not just once before running parent loop again.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
      for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)  
          {            
          if(i == c)
              System.out.print("*");
          else
              System.out.print("-");
          }
    System.out.println(".");//The . would get printed 10 times as it is inside first for loop.
}
```

Comment: What does this mean? Include words.

Answer (score 1):

This confusion is because of the absence of **Curly Braces**. Your code has nothing wrong in it. The last `System.out.println(".");` which is confusing you is part of the outer loop. So your code is equivalent to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
      for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {                 
          if(i == c){
              System.out.print("*");
          }
           else{
              System.out.print("-");
          }
    System.out.println(".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Sysout in your code belongs to the outer loop and not inner loop.

If you don't put curly braces after your for loop it just takes only 1 statement after it.

This should work in your case.

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
      for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)                  
       {   if(i == c)
              System.out.print("*");
          else
              System.out.print("-");

    System.out.println(".");}
     }
 }
```